# Can I have different sqlite databases with different set of tables in iOS?

Tags: sqlite, iso

In my iOS app I am planning to give offline support. My plan is here, for every user I will have a separate *.sqlite* db file which stores the user specific information. And I also want to have a general.sqlite db file to store the general information.

Is this possible using core data in sqlite?.